# Android Studio - Update to Electric Eel 2022.1.1 breaks dart files icons

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

After Android Studio upgrade (channel stable) I'm getting this in project view:

[image]

Dart files should have icon on the left, I'm getting white background instead. Other file types and folders are fine.

Do you know any workaround?

Comment: I faced the same issue but the icons are as here  [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvm1a.png)

Comment: So only light theme is affected? I don't want dark colors

Comment: both light and dark are affected. In dark it should display dart icon instead of what you saw in dark

Comment: I submitted a bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265547226

Comment: Isn't that dart plugin bug? If so, it should be submitted to Jetbrains

Comment: i submitted from Android Studio(Help -> Submit Feedback), it redirected to google's issue tracker since it is Google's co-product

Comment: I opened a duplicate (didn't find the other issue with search) with screenshots and recording: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/265555854

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dart plugin with the fix for Android Studio 2022.1.1 has been published, please update.

Comment: More specifically plugin version 221.6096 fixes it

Comment: That has happened again in the last version. Could you please solve it?

Comment: Sorry for the glitch. The new Dart plugin update version 221.6103.1 should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and installing again dart plugin will solve this problem. Also make sure you have installed latest version of dart plugin install [Dart 222.4560](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart/versions/stable)

Comment: Plugin update pulled? Not appearing as available update in ma case, 221.6096 is latest available

Comment: You can install it by download the plugin. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kFEWDsj2zs2ajMdGFuZO4jcF3I6ly5An/view?usp=share_link. Select .jar file. But before that make sure you uninstall the dart plugin.

Comment: Ok, but what for?